# Game in Java is not displaying

Tags: java, graphics, applet, actionlistener, bluej

Hello everyone I am trying to make a game where the user plays as some kind of character, and trys to collect coins while avoiding monsters that spawn. My program compiles with no error, but nothing is showing up when I run the applet. This could be because of the order of extension I have everything in but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated (this is for a final school project for my intro to Java class). Here is the code, I know it is long but it all pertains to the question at hand:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Sprite extends JApplet
{
   Image image;
   int x, y;
   boolean isVisible;
   public Sprite()
   {
       isVisible = false;
       image = null;
   }
   public Sprite(Image i)
   {
       isVisible = true;
       image = i;
       x = 10;
       y = 10;
   }
   public void setImage(Image img)
   {
       image = img;
       isVisible = true;
   }
   public void setLocation(int _x, int _y)
   {
       x = _x;
       y = _y;
   }
   public Rectangle getDimensions()
   {
       return new Rectangle(x, y, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
   }
public boolean intersects(Sprite s)
{
    return getDimensions().intersects(s.getDimensions());
}
public void setVisible(boolean vis)
{
    isVisible = vis;
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(isVisible)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }
}
}
class Coins extends Sprite
{
int amount;
public Coins(int amt)
{
    amount = amt;
}
public int getAmount()
{
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amt)
{
    amount = amt;
}
}
class AnimateSprite extends Sprite
{
int speed = 5;
int directionX = 1, directionY = 1;
int healthPoints = 100;
final boolean DEAD = false;
final boolean ALIVE = true;
public void moveUp()
{
    y -= speed;
}
public void moveDown()
{
    y += speed;
}
public void moveLeft()
{
    x -= speed;
}
public void moveRight()
{
    x += speed;
}
public int getHealthPoints()
{
    return healthPoints;
}
public void setHealthPoints(int hp)
{
    healthPoints = hp;
}
public boolean hit(int amt)
{
    healthPoints -= amt;
    if(healthPoints < 0)
    return DEAD;
    else
    return ALIVE;
 }
}
class Game extends AnimateSprite implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
 AnimateSprite user;
 AnimateSprite monster, troll;
 Coins ten, twenty;
 Thread thread;
 Random r;
 public void init()
 {
    r = new Random();
    user = new AnimateSprite();
    user.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "player.gif"));
    monster = new AnimateSprite();
    monster.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
    troll = new AnimateSprite();
    troll.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
    troll.setLocation(350, 350);
    setupCoins();
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
 }
 public void setupCoins()
 {
    ten = new Coins(10);
    twenty = new Coins(20);
    ten.setLocation(400, 350);
    twenty.setLocation(450, 50);
    ten.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "coins.gif"));
    twenty.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "coins.gif"));
 }
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) //Event handling
 {
    int key = ke.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    user.moveUp();
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    user.moveDown();
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    user.moveLeft();
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    user.moveRight();
 }
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {}
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {}
 public void update(Graphics g) {paint(g);}
 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    ten.paintComponent(g);
    twenty.paintComponent(g);
    monster.setLocation(r.nextInt(10) - 5 + monster.x, r.nextInt(10 - 5 + monster.y));
    monster.paintComponent(g);
    user.paintComponent(g);
    if(user.intersects(monster))
    {
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 26));
            g.drawString("YOU HAVE DIED, YOU LOSE!", 20, 100); //Prints this when you lose
            thread.interrupt(); //Stopping the thread if you die
        }
 }
 public void run()
 {
    try //Try catch
    {
        while(true) //Only does this while when the boolean is true
        {
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10); //Thread sleeps
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {} //Exception handling
 }
 }
```

Comment: Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` to `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of inheritance seems odd, but its not whats causing the problem. Take a look at this website: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/28410-application-to-japplet-and-reverse/

Java Applets need to have `init()`, `start()`, `stop()`, and `destroy()`. You will need to put these methods in your `Sprite` class for the Applet to function.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I actually fixed it with the order I had things in. It now displays the character, and the monster and lets me move towards coins (although it is extremely buggy, and I have yet to add any kind of counter for the coins). Your answer would work as well though.

Comment: Playing around with applets, I figured out that you don't actually need those methods. I believe that you just need to override the `paint()` or `paintComponent()`. But as long as you have it working, it doesn't matter too much